# Possible to replace string if match string in two files?

Tags: linux, shell-script, command-line, python, programming

i am aware of this doable by sed but only limited to one string
let me explain let better, lets say in file 1 we got something like this

```
tom,123456789
steve,1478321
jon,315457
```

and in the second file file

```
tania,148321
john,123456789
```

so if a string in the second file matches the value in the first it will replace the value in the first file. Note i stink in programming i know this is prrettyy much doable via python or something but im clueless in them

Comment: Easy to do in `awk`. Read the second file into an array whose keys are the strings you want to match. Then when reading the first file, check if there's a matching array element and perform the replacement.

Comment: Or, Barmar's method, but read the first file first, then the second in the same way (allowing the matching keys be replaced in the array) and  then write the array at the end.

Comment: i almost have no experience in awk, how can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to replace the *first* field if the *second* field matches, then you could use something like this:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$2]=$1; next} $2 in a {$1=a[$2]} 1' OFS=, file2 file1
john,123456789
steve,1478321
jon,315457
```

Comment: well it didn't work , its the five field on the first file and the first on the second file, the first file fields are separated by ","